# How to get access to object, angular 4

Tags: angular

I have this array in my DataComponent and want to inject 'string4' to my ConsumeComponent via a Service:

```js
export class DataComponent {
  mystring: string = '';

  constructor(private myService: myService) {}

  data = [
    {
      string1: '',
      string2: '',
      string3: '',
      string4: ''
    }
  ];

  consumefunction() {
    this.mystring = this.data.values['string4'];
    this.myService.anotherfunc(this.mystring);
  }
}
```

But I didn't get acces to the object 'string4' with the line:

```
this.data.values['string4'];
```

Comment: `this.data[0].string4` will get the value

Comment: @jrelo that only gives typings, it doesnt solve the issue

Comment: @mast3rd3mon You are right, I was wrong to interpret the problem

Comment: What was the downvote for???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` is an array of objects, if you want to retrieve a property from the object in the array, you need to do the following:

- `this.data` will get you the `data` object you defined as an array, the code encapsulated with `[` `]`.
- `this.data[0]` will get you the first object of the array. In your case, there is only one, the piece of code encapsulated with `{` `}`.
- `this.data[0].string4` will get you the property you want from this first object.

In short:

```js
this.mystring = this.data[0].string4;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with the code.  One is that `data` is a local variable in the constructor, not member variable in the class, so it cannot be accessed through `this.data`.  The second issue is that `value` field is missing in data.

With the following changes you should be able to access it

```js
export class DataComponent {

     mystring: string = '';

     constructor(private myService: myService) {}

     // change this line
     this.data = {
        values: {
          string1: '',
          string2: '',
          string3: '',
          string4: ''
        }
     };

      consumefunction () {

      this.mystring = this.data.values['string4'];

      this.myService.anotherfunc(this.mystring);

      }
```

}